# How Can I access an input field on an existing webpage from Javascript project

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, input-field

I want to have an input field to which I can type a text, and when I press the button, I need that text to be pasted in the input field of a webpage, like Facebook's login input field.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can use javascript code to get the input text when the button is clicked, then use AJAX to send the text to the webpage.

Comment: Are you trying to take the value from one `<input>` and transfer it to another `<input>`? Your post isn't very clear (*to me*). Have you tried anything for this yet or do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can pass the value of a text field on HTML to your JS file.

HTML:

`<input id="input" type="text">`

JS:

`let input = document.getElementById("input").value;`

Now you can pass this value to any other element or field on the same webpage using JS.

Hope this helps you to get started.